# Remove all widgets after clicking button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am creating a login/sign-up system using tkinter. When the user clicks on either login or sign-up, I want all widgets to disappear for new widgets to appear on the screen depending on if they clicked on login or sign-up. So if they clicked on login, new labels and textboxes would appear for their username and password. The problem is I am using .place() and the tutorials I have seen are mostly using `pack_forget` or `grid_forget`

**My Code:**

```
from tkinter import *


class Window:

    def __init__(self, master):

        root.title("Sign Up or Login")
        root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
        root.maxsize(width=300,height=300)

        self.login_button = Button(master, text = "Login", width=18,height=4, command=self.LoginPage)
        self.signup_button = Button(master, text = "Sign Up", width=18,height=4, command=self.SignupPage)

        self.login_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        self.signup_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)

    def LoginPage(self):
        root.title("Login")

    def SignupPage(self):
        root.title("Sign Up")



root = Tk()

run = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

**My Interface:**

[image: Interface]

Comment: Did you try `place_forget`?

Comment: fhdrsdg oh that works ty

Comment: You can also `destroy()` the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter you use `place`,`pack` or `grid`. The best solution works for all:

```
for widgets in root.winfo_children():
    widgets.destory()
```

It loops through widgets and delete them. You can try:

```
from tkinter import *


class Window:

    def __init__(self, master):

        root.title("Sign Up or Login")
        root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
        root.maxsize(width=300,height=300)

        self.login_button = Button(master, text = "Login", width=18,height=4, command=self.LoginPage)
        self.signup_button = Button(master, text = "Sign Up", width=18,height=4, command=self.SignupPage)

        self.login_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
        self.signup_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)

    def LoginPage(self):
        root.title("Login")
        self.Restore()
    def SignupPage(self):
        root.title("Sign Up")
        self.Restore()
    def Restore(self):
            for widgets in root.winfo_children():
                widgets.destroy()


root = Tk()

run = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```